# Calendario em php mudando a cor da div

Tags: php

Bom dia pessoal, peguei esse calendário na internet e preciso que ele altere a cor quando tiver uma agenda no banco de dados. Vejam:

```
$data = date('d/m/Y');

                    $data_explode = explode("/", $data);

                    $dia = $data_explode[0];
                    $mes = $data_explode[1];
                    $ano = $data_explode[2];
                    $calendario = "";

                    $v_mes = substr($mes, 0, 2);
                    $novo_mes = (int) $mes - 1;

                    $ultimo_dia_mes = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, $ano));

                    $vetor_dias_semana = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

                    $vetor_mes = array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Mar&ccedil;o", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");

                    $calendario .="<div class='cabecalho_semana'>DOM</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>SEG</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>TER</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>QUA</div><div div class='cabecalho_semana'>QUI</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>SEX</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>SAB</div>";
                    $contador = 1;

                    $dia_semana_primeiro_dia = $dia_semana = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, $ano));

                    $trava = "F";
                    $inicio = 1;

                    $dados = connection::select("select * from agenda where data_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio'");
                    $reg = $dados->fetchObject();
                    if (!empty($reg)) {
                        $cor = 'aaa';
                    } else {
                        $cor = '';
                    }

                    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
                        if ($dia_semana_primeiro_dia == $i || $trava == "T") {
                            $calendario .="<div class='cabecalho_dia' value='$inicio/$mes/$ano'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "-" . $cor . "</a></div>";
                            $trava = "T";
                            $inicio++;
                        } else {
                            $calendario .="<div class='cabecalho_dia'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
                        }
                    }

                    $fim = "F";
                    $linha_semana = 1;
                    while ($fim == "F" || $linha_semana < 6) {

                        for ($f = 0; $f < 7; $f++) {

                            $linha_semana++;

                            if ($inicio <= $ultimo_dia_mes) {

                                $calendario .="<div class='cabecalho_dia' value='$inicio/$mes/$ano'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "-" . $cor . "</a></div>";

                                if ($inicio == $ultimo_dia_mes) {
                                    $fim = "T";
                                }
                                $inicio++;
                            } else {
                                $calendario .="<div class='cabecalho_dia'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $html = str_replace('#CALENDARIO#', $calendario, $html);

                    return $html;
```

Nessa parte abaixo é que faço a verificação:

```
$dados = connection::select("select * from agenda where data_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio'");
                    $reg = $dados->fetchObject();
                     if (!empty($reg)) {
                        $cor = 'aaa';
                    } else {
                        $cor = '';
                    }
```

Comment: Esse codigo funciona? Ou seja, a cor é definida corretamente

Comment: Funciona sim. Coloquei um caractere (aaa) para facilitar o entendimento.